# SQL Server View get count from related table where column = "True"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have two related tables in SQL Server in a 1 to many relationship (Applicant, Reference).

I want a view that will retrieve all the data from the Applicant table and also add another column to the view that tells me how many related Reference rows there are where the "Complete" column is True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using a subquery:

```
select applicantfield1, applicantfield2, 
  (select count(*) from 
  reference where reference.applicantkey = applicant.applicantkey 
  and reference.complete = 1) AS referencecount
from applicant
```

Unless the complete field is in the applicant table (not the reference table).  If so, it would be more like this:

```
select applicantfield1, applicantfield2, 
  (select count(*) from 
  reference where 
  reference.applicantkey = applicant.applicantkey) AS referencecount
from applicant
where applicant.complete = 1
```

Comment: Obviously you'll need to replace my made up column names, and foreign key fields with the real ones.

Comment: The first answer you gave is the one I was looking for.  I just tested it, and it appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below.  You need to join on a table.  This will handle where the applicant also doesn't have a True reference.

```
SELECT A.*, isnull(r.comptotal,0) as CompleteTotal 
FROM Applicant as a Left Join 
   (SELECT ApplicantId, Count(Complete) as comptotal
    FROM Reference Where Complete=1 Group by ApplicantID) as r 
    on a.ApplicantId = r.applicantId
```